# How did Fortran prevent recursion prior to Fortran 90?

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran

I have been reading a bit about programming languages and saw that prior to Fortran 90 recursion was not permitted. How was indirect recursion prevented?

While I see how direct recursion (inside the body of the function itself) can be trivially detected, the problem seems much harder in the general case.

Comment: It just means it doesn't have to work. It doesn't have to be detected.

Comment: I see, so was the behavior undefined if you recursed?

Comment: It is likely more technically correct to say the program was non-conforming.

Comment: Some of the pre-F77 vendor specific compilers (like PRIME) allowed recursion.  The depth of recursion had to be specified.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments on this question note, recursion was prohibited simply by saying that recursion was not allowed.  Fortran 77 for example has the statement:

> A subprogram  must not reference itself, either directly or indirectly.

The consequence of this is that it is a restriction on the programmer to ensure that recursion doesn't happen, and a [compiler can assume that this condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558908/3157076).<sup>1</sup>

Fortran 90 permitted recursion, and from then up to Fortran 2008 a subprogram which is to be potentially used recursively must have the `recursive` prefix.

Even in Fortran 2018 (where allowing recursion is the default), correct use of recursion is a restriction on the program:

> The NON_RECURSIVE *prefix-spec* shall not appear if any procedure defined by the subprogram directly or indirectly invokes itself

This remains even now something that the compiler is not required to validate.

---

<sup>1</sup> The discussion in the answer about detection of violations doesn't truly apply to Fortran 77.  Back then, a compiler could be much more trusting of the programmer to give a correct program.