# What is: 'iunit' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Tags: fortran, gfortran, dex, geany

I am using:

```
  open(iunit,file=dexfile,status='old',iostat=status)
   if(status /= 0)then
     write(*,*) 'Unable to open dex file'
   endif
```

in Geany, but get this error:

```
Warning: 'iunit' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of the Variables?

Comment: `iunit` should be an integer and given a value before `open` statement. Perhaps even be an `parameter`

Comment: You should really show more code. See [ask] and [mcve]. The code you show is insufficient to reproduce the error. All variables should be declared and `implicit none` should be used.

Comment: Although the code fragment is incomplete, we still can explain what the error message means.  We can't answer _what_ the correction should be, or whether the compiler is correct in its assessment, but this is still a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler has this option, you can use the `newunit` command in function `open` to return a flag to an available unit ID upon opening:

`open(newunit=iunit,file=dexfile,status='old',iostat=status)`

In this case, the `open` command will return a value of `iunit` as *output* to that call, instead of *input*.

Otherwise, you could cook a snippet that does that for you, for example:

```
! Find a logical unit which is not currently in use
integer function first_available_unit() result(iunit)
   logical :: is_open
   
   do iunit=10,999 ! Skip units 1-10 as they're sometimes system reserved
      inquire(unit=iunit,opened=is_open)
      if (.not.is_open) return
   end do
end function first_available_unit
```

and then run:

```
   iunit = first_available_unit()
   open(unit=iunit,file=dexfile,status='old',iostat=status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `iunit` something like this:

```
integer, parameter      :: iunit = 11
```

It doesn't have to be with the `parameter` but I normally do this because it doesnt have to change during execution and if I have multiple open files it is less error prone since it cannot be altered.

Comment: It is not necessary for the value to be a constant. Its value just has to be defined.

Comment: Don't define a unit with values smaller than 10, as these can / are used by the system for e.g. stdout / stderr etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are times in the life of a Fortran program where the value of a variable must be referenced/known: the variable must be defined.  The warning message you get from the compiler is it reporting that it is confident you haven't given `iunit` a value.  In general it [isn't the compiler's job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558908/3157076) to check that you have defined all variables before referencing them, but when the compiler can check it may report so.

`iunit` in this case must be defined because its value is used to be the unit for a file connection.  Once we know what the warning means we have two answers which suggest approaches to correct the identified issue:

- be sure to check that you've given a value (and check for typos in variable names, such as by using `implicit none`)
- use `newunit=iunit` instead of `[unit=]iunit`: here you don't need to specify a value, because the compiler chooses an appropriate value for you.