# Changing intent(in) variables through a pointer

Tags: pointers, fortran

I'm wondering if it is legal/safe to modify `intent(in)` dummy arguments through pointers associated with corresponding actual arguments. Specifically when the pointer association was established before the subroutine call.

For example, is the following OK (it seems to work fine with gfortran)?

```
program test
implicit none

type compound
  integer, allocatable :: A1(:)
  integer, pointer :: A2(:,:)
end type compound

type(compound), target :: my
integer :: n=5, i

allocate(my%A1(n**2))
my%A2(1:n,1:n) => my%A1(:)

do i=1,n**2
  my%A1(i) = i
end do

do i=1,n
  print *, my%A2(i,:)
end do

call assign_A(my)

do i=1,n
  print *, my%A2(i,:)
end do

contains

subroutine assign_A(var)
type(compound), intent(in) :: var
var%A2(:,:) = 42
end subroutine

end program test
```

The trick is a user-defined type that contains a pointer and a target, the former pointing to the latter. An instance of this is passed as `intent(in)` and in the subroutine it is modified through the pointer component (the values pointed by `intent(in)` pointers can be modified). I'm a bit surprised that this works, but maybe it's just a missing diagnostic by the compiler. If I was changing `var%A1` directly that would of course fail.

EDIT: Output from the above program (compiled with gfortran 7.5.0):

```
       1           6          11          16          21
       2           7          12          17          22
       3           8          13          18          23
       4           9          14          19          24
       5          10          15          20          25
      42          42          42          42          42
      42          42          42          42          42
      42          42          42          42          42
      42          42          42          42          42
      42          42          42          42          42
```

Comment: What are you taking to be your "`intent(in)` actual argument"?  The only thing with an intent attribute isn't an actual argument as I read your example.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP means "`intent(in)` dummy argument"

Comment: @francescalus I mean the actual argument that's passed as an `intent(in)` dummy argument.

Comment: Please add the program output to the post also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not allowed to change the value of an `intent(in)` object in this way. The compiler does not have to (be able to) tell you that you are doing something wrong. (Further, it is an unreasonable expectation to have on a compiler that it should be able to detect all cases where an illegal change is made.)

The dummy argument `var` is a non-pointer object, and this means that its components also have the same intent attribute. You are trying to define `var` and its component `var%A1` by the assignment `var%A2(:,:) = 42` because `var%A2` is pointer associated with `my%A1` (through the argument association of `var` with `my`); through argument association of `var` and `my`, definition of `my%A1` is definition of `var%A1`.

This is a violation of the statement that (F2018 8.5.10 p2):

> The INTENT (IN) attribute for a nonpointer dummy argument specifies that it shall neither be defined nor become undefined during the invocation and execution of the procedure.

However, this is not a numbered constraint or syntax rule so the compiler is not required to be capable of [diagnosing the violation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558908/3157076). Where a compiler is required to be capable of diagnosing a violation for changing `var` is in (F2018 C844 (R826)):

> A nonpointer object with the INTENT (IN) attribute shall not appear in a variable definition context (19.6.7).

A variable definition context is specific, and the assignment statement of the question is not a variable definition context for `var` or `var%A1`. An assignment such as `var%A1=42` (which you note your compiler complains about) is appearance, of `var%A1` (but not `var`), in a variable definition context.

You can also wonder whether the aliasing restrictions come into play.

In summary, it is possible to hide changes to a dummy variable with `intent(in)` from your compiler. Just as programmers don't like being tricked, your compiler doesn't have to still be your friend if you do this. The compiler can assume `var` doesn't change value during the subroutine and it owes you nothing if you find a way to subvert that.