# Gfortran type mismatch error despite "-fallow-argument-mismatch" flag

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Gfortran 10 added the default behavior to make type mismatches an error instead of a warning. The flag `-fallow-argument-mismatch` can be used to degrade the errors to warnings. However, within the same fortran file and using gcc 13 with the `-fallow-argument-mismatch`, gfortran fires a few warnings (as expected) and one error here:

```
call test(ter,file,0,'legacy')

                                                      
subroutine test(ander,file,mmr,status)                                                                                                                    
  implicit none
  integer(kind=8) :: mmr
                ....
```

Why is this particular mismatch different in a way that it is not considered a warning?

I could fix this by doing:

```
call test(ter,file,INT8(0),'legacy')
```

However, I thought this was the reason of using `-fallow-argument-mismatch` at compile time. My compilation command is as follow:

```
gfortran -mfma -O3 -m64 -Ofast -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=0 -fPIC -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -fallow-invalid-boz -fallow-argument-mismatch -fbackslash -fno-fast-math -c mem.f90 -o mem.o
```

What is expected in `mmr` is an integer 0,1,>1 or <0.

Comment: What exact compilation command do you use? Can you show a full MRE?

Comment: Passing 0 into an integer of a different size is just very wrong, it is not one of those legacy tricks that are not standard conforming but in practice work. This one is plain wrong. It may work by pure luck but on other platforms it will fail.

Comment: To stress how important the [mre] is, note that `-fallow-argument-mismatch` relates to _external_ procedures. Plenty of procedures aren't external and the compiler may well want to be a lot more fussy (as I would want it to be). The error suppression is to allow important older libraries still to be used, in ways like the completely illegal `call vital_external_sub(1); call vital_external_sub('a'); end`, not to allow sloppy writing in modern code.

Comment: A better question might be "Why not fix the code?".  gfortran is telling you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @steve Sure, but not always possible

Comment: The point is that as mentioned by @VladimirFГероямслава, what gfortran is reporting here is a severe coding error and not just a "beyond the standard" trick. You should NOT leave such a code uncorrected.

Comment: You have the source code.  It is **always** possible to fix the bug.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава What would be the right way of doing this? Declaring an integer(kind=8) and make it 0,1 or any other integer, than passing it to the test subroutine? Casting the integer parameters INT8(0)?

Comment: @PierU For the record, the Intel compiler does not report any error nor warning.

Comment: The standard doesn't require the compilers to track and report such an error. Still, it's definitly an error. The simplest way to fix it is to pass `0_8` instead of `0`. This syntax means "the zero value of the kind=8 integer type"

Comment: @PierU wouldn't that be the same than `INT8(0)` ?

Comment: The end result is the same. However: `int8(0)` is probably evaluated at runtime, while `0_8` is set at compile time; but more importantly the `int8()` function is not standard and hence not guaranteed to be portable.

Comment: That said, `kind=8` is not portable either (but at least it is standard). In principle it's better to write `kind=int64` and `0_int64`, `int64` being provided by the `iso_fortran_env` module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type mismatches are a violation of the Fortran standard's [restriction on program units](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558908/3157076). A compiler is not required to be able to detect and report such violations, but may choose to.

Consider the (non-Fortran) program:

```
program broken
  implicit none(external)
  external sub

  call sub(1)
  call sub(1.)
end program
```

This violates the Fortran standard's (long standing) rules on procedure references and many compilers will tell you that. Starting in GCC 10, gfortran complains about this by default and provides the option `-fallow-argument-mismatch` to allow the many broken Fortran sources to still be compiled, just like earlier versions of gfortran compiled them.<sup>1</sup>

The `-fallow-argument-mismatch` option is described as:

```
       -fallow-argument-mismatch
           Some code contains calls to external procedures with
           mismatches between the calls and the procedure
           definition, or with mismatches between different
           calls. Such code is non-conforming, and will usually
           be flagged wi1th an error.  This options degrades the
           error to a warning, which can only be disabled by
           disabling all warnings vial -w.  Only a single
           occurrence per argument is flagged by this warning.
           -fallow-argument-mismatch is implied by -std=legacy.
```

Note "external".

The non-Fortran source

```
program brokeninternal
  implicit none

  call sub(1)

contains
  subroutine sub(x)
    real x
  end subroutine sub

end program brokeninternal
```

has a type mismatch and no use of `-fallow-argument-mismatch` is going to let you get away with it. The procedure `sub` is internal, thus having an explicit interface<sup>2</sup>; compilers have used explicit interfaces for yonks to check arguments. The type of "yonks" which goes back to when explicit interfaces came to be. There's no legacy of missing diagnostics or illegal-but-useful use to support.

---

<sup>1</sup> Violation of the Fortran standard or not, such broken Fortran programs are useful. Other Fortran compilers which have complained for ages still let users insist on compiling them.

<sup>2</sup> An external procedure may have an explicit interface, and `-fallow-argument-mismatch` will not allow such mis-matching. gfortran can (now) detect characteristic mismatches with an implicit interface in some cases, notably when the external procedure is defined in the same file as the place referencing it, and `-fallow-argument-mismatch` may have an effect.

Comment: Nice concise answer.  A bit of history.  The gfortran developer, who introduced argument checking to gfortran, was concerned that his patch would break many legacy codes.   Having just introduced the `-fallow-invalid-boz` option, I suggested that he provide an option to gracefully degrade an error to a warning.  The `-fallow-argument-mismatch` has been a blessing (for users) and a curse (for gfortran bug reports).

Comment: @steve, I've supported enough users with the answer "fix your code instead of blaming the tools" to last a lifetime, even without ever being an actual compiler developer. Diagnostics are good, but yes, there must be pragmatism.